# How to calculate the average of timestamps

Tags: lua, unix-timestamp

I have a .log file that looks like this :

```
--hh:mm:ss
10:15:46
10:09:33
10:27:26
10:09:49
09:54:21
10:10:25
```

And what I need to do is to calculate the average on those timestamps, I wrote a function to calculate the average :

```
function calculate_average_working_hours(working_day_diff)

local current_hour, current_minutes, current_secondes = 0, 0, 0
    local total_hour, total_minutes, total_secondes = 0, 0, 0
    local working_days_counter = #working_day_diff

    for key, value in pairs(working_day_diff) do
        current_hour, current_minutes, current_secondes = extract_timestamp_value(value) --covert the values to numbers
        total_hour = total_hour + current_hour
        total_minutes = total_minutes + current_minutes
        total_secondes = total_secondes + current_secondes
    end

    total_hour = math.ceil(total_hour / working_days_counter)
    total_minutes = math.ceil(total_minutes / working_days_counter)
    total_secondes = math.ceil(total_secondes / working_days_counter)

    return ("%02d:%02d"):format(total_hour, total_minutes)
end
```

So basically what I'm doing is to sum the seconds, minutes, and hours and divide the results by the number of logs, 
for example if i have `10:15:46` and `10:09:33` i will add the seconds, minutes and hours and divide it by 2

is this the correct way to calculate the average of timestamps values?

Comment: By averaging the unix timestamps? 1970-01-01T10:15:46 = 36946

Comment: No, convert each of the stamps to a _single_ value in a resolution that interests you (e.g. seconds); so that `10:09:33` becomes `10 * 3600 + 9 * 60 + 33`. After that proceed with normal average calculations. Consider how your function behaves with dataset of `"10:59:10", "11:01:12"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would be something like this solved the problem:

```
--- example 1
local log = [[--hh:mm:ss
10:15:46
10:09:33
10:27:26
10:09:49
09:54:21
10:10:25
]]

local function seconds(v) 
    local h,m,s = v:match("(%d%d):(%d%d):(%d%d)") 
    if h and m and s then return h*3600+m*60+s else return nil end 
end
local i,sum = 0, 0
for line in log:gmatch('(.-)[\r\n]') do    
    local r = seconds(line)
    if r then i=i+1; sum = sum+r end
end
print(sum,i, os.date("!%X",sum/i) )
```

Comment: Thank you Mike, that's a much better approach. just a couple of followup questions if you don't mind, what does the `!` character purpose? I couldn't find it on the docs. And the second question -  the interpreter is complaining that the second argument to date should be number, is there any arm in doing `sum // i` , whats the loss value?

Comment: `!` character at first position - its a sign of UTC, otherwise you will get a local timezone [link](https://github.com/lua/lua/blob/d12262068d689eacc452a459a021df0ad8f6d46c/loslib.c#L288) , second I didn't understand, sorry.